# Not able to delete data from mapping table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, delete-row

I have 2 entity One is Header and another one is Items

Header has many items

Header code as below

```
@Entity
public class Headertable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int headerId;

  private String headerText;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="itemId.header",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
  ...
  getter and setters for these
```

and Item table as below

```
@Entity
public class Items {

  @EmbeddedId
  private ItemId itemId;

  private String itemData;
  .... getter and setters for these
```

Item table id class

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemId implements Serializable{

  @ManyToOne
  private Headertable header;

  private int itemId;
  ...setter and getters
```

Here is the test code to delete one item from the Header as below

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Headertable header = (Headertable) session.get(Headertable.class, 1);

    Iterator<Items> iterator = header.getItems().iterator();
    while( iterator.hasNext() )
    {
      Items items = iterator.next();
      if( items.getItemData().equals("chiru"))
      {
        iterator.remove();
      }
    }
    session.saveOrUpdate(header);
    Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
    transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the item:

`session.delete(items);`

Removing the reference from the inverse side has no impact to the saved data if `orphanRemoval` is not used.

Comment: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag it is throwing this exception

Comment: Not the collection, but the variable `items` of type `Items`.